# ¿Cómo mostrar una tabla (segunda) anexa a una primera, desde html?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Tengo una pagina html que muestra una tabla extraída desde PHPMyAdmin, la tabla principal, tiene otra anexada o anidada, pero no se como agregarla al código principal y hacer que la muestre.

```
<body>

        <section class="principal">
            
            <div class="block1">
                <label for="caja_busqueda">Seleccionar origen</label>
                <br>
                <!--<div id="buscador"></div>-->
                <select id="caja_busqueda" name="origen" class="form-control"></select>



                <div class="block2">
                    <label>Tipo de dato</label>
                    <br>
                    <select id="segundaSel"></select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="datos"></div>

        </section>
    </body>
```

En el html, tengo dos selectores, los cuales me permiten filtrar la tabla; y la misma tabla, se llama y muestra a través del div "datos".

```
<?php 
    
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "ejemplo";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if($conn->connect_error){
        die("Conexión fallida: ".$conn->connect_error);
      }

    $salida = "";

    $query = "SELECT * FROM jugadores WHERE Name NOT LIKE '' ORDER By Id_no LIMIT 25";
    
    if (isset($_POST['consulta'])) {
        $q = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['consulta']);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM jugadores WHERE Id_no LIKE '%$q%' OR Name LIKE '%$q%' OR ClubName LIKE '%$q%' OR Rtg_Nat LIKE '%$q%' OR Title LIKE '$q' ";
    }

    /*if (isset($_POST['buscar'])){
        $q = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['buscar']);
        $query = "SELECT Name FROM jugadores";
    }*/

    $resultado = $conn->query($query);

    if ($resultado->num_rows > 0) {

        $salida.="<table border=1 class='tabla_datos'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr id='titulo'>
                            <td>ID</td>
                            <td>Jugador</td>
                            <td>Nombre Club</td>
                            <td>Rating Nacional</td>
                            <td>Titulo</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>";

        while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
            $salida.="<tr>
                        <td>".$fila['Id_no']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['Name']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['ClubName']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['Rtg_Nat']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['Title']."</td>
                    </tr>";
        }

        $salida.="</tbody></table>";
        
    }else{
        $salida.="No hay datos :(";
    }

    echo $salida;
    $conn->close();
 ?>
```

En el PHP, hago la conexión con la BD y llamo a la tabla primaria, pero esta tabla esta enlazada a otra, la cual contiene datos que deseo mostrar a traves de algun link que pueda agregar en alguna columna.

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español, mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Lo ideal es que añadas tu código con lo que has intentado. Saludos.

Comment: En SQL las tablas se unen mediante consultas del tipo `JOIN`, para traer juntos los resultados de dos o más tablas relacionadas entre sí.

Comment: Pero si quisiera mostrar la segunda tabla en una nueva pagina, como debiese hacerlo? y como podría colocar como "link" en una columna de la primera tabla, para que me dirija a la segunda?